# OpenVPN and VPC peering - How to resolve .compute.internal domains in two different accounts with BIND9

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, bind, amazon-vpc

At our company we have three AWS accounts, the main one, used as "root" account for IAM and hosting an OpenVPN Access Server. The other two accounts are `pro` and `stg`. Each one has its own VPC, with different IP ranges, and we have a VPC peering between the root and pro accounts, and other one between root and stg. IP routing is already setup and everything is under control from this side.

(I'm sorry I can't upload images yet, so here you have the link)
[VPN+VPC-Peering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTuPT.jpg)

The problem comes with DNS resolution. The setup is this one:

I've installed BIND9 in the OpenVPN server, to allow DNS forwarding for private hosted domains, using a configuration like this one in `named.conf.local`

```
zone "stg-my-internal-domain.com" IN {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 10.229.1.100;10.229.2.100; };
};


zone "pro-my-internal-domain.com" IN {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 10.228.1.100;10.228.2.100; };
};
```

And also two Route53 inbound resolvers (a simple BIND server running on each VPC also works) running in 10.229.1.100 and 10.229.2.100 for `stg` and 10.228.1.100 10.228.2.100 for `pro` account

VPN clients have OpenVPN profiles that use the Access Server as DNS resolver.

From my client, I can resolve both `my-service-1.pro-my-internal-domain.com` and `my-service-2.stg-my-internal-domain.com` perfectly, but the problem comes when I want to resolve internal domain names like the ones that AWS generates inside each VPC with `my-service-2.eu-west-1.compute.internal`

I know that this is an anti-pattern and I should always use the private domain as much as I can, but for some cases like EMR clusters, YARN and Hadoop managers use links that reference to the internal AWS names, making the resolution impossible.

So my question is: Is there any way to configure DNS to delegate resolution to a secondary address if primary fails?

I could set up a forwarder for the `eu-west-1.compute.internal` zone using all the accounts resolvers, but
DNS specification says that the secondary nameserver will only be used if the first one is unreachable, so as far as it answers an empty or "unknown" response, it's still a valid response and the second one will not be queried.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using route53 private domain?

Comment: We are already using them like in `my-service-1.pro-my-internal-domain.com` but our main issue is that YARN manager for instance, uses AWS hostnames (the ones with the `.compute.internal` domain) for the links and therefore we need to resolve those ones.

Comment: Ah OK. Why not just change the internal host name to a public dns name? Those services are using the hostname assigned to them. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html

Comment: Did you get a chance to try this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the internal host name to a public dns name? Those services are using the hostname assigned to them of course. You can change it. 
See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html

You may (or may not)  need to assign fixed private ips to each. In any case publish this private IP in a public DNS zone. You should then be able to resolve these names properly. Note you can also have a script run on each instance on startup,  to update the hostname and dns record.

For a good discussion on private ip addresses in public DNS, see https://serverfault.com/questions/4458/private-ip-address-in-public-dns

For reference, here is the best answer there:

> Some people will say no public DNS records should ever disclose private IP addresses....with the thinking being that you are giving potential attackers a leg up on some information that might be required to exploit private systems. Personally, I think that obfuscation is a poor form of security, especially when we are talking about IP addresses because in general they are easy to guess anyway, so I don't see this as a realistic security compromise. The bigger consideration here is making sure your public users don't pickup this DNS record as part of the normal public services of your hosted application. ie: External DNS lookups somehow start resolving to an address they can't get to. Aside from that, I see no fundamental reason why putting private address A records into the public space is a problem....especially when you have no alternate DNS server to host them on. If you do decide to put this record into the public DNS space, you might consider creating a separate zone on the same server to hold all the "private" records. This will make it clearer that they are intended to be private....however for just one A record, I probably wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

AWS only supports DNS resolution of these internal ipv4 DNS hostnames if your VPN is in the same region as your EMR cluster (or any other compute resource). I have reached out to their Support and they have confirmed this.

For example, I have an AWS Client VPN endpoint setup in Frankfurt and an EMR cluster in Ireland. I am pushing to my host the private DNS server of the VPC (and all other related config is enabled in both VPCs) so that I can resolve private Route53 DNS zone records.

While I am connected to the VPN,

I can't resolve this:

```
$ dig +short ip-10-11-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal
$
```

But I can resolve the following, which is an instance that's in the same region as the VPN endpoint:

```
$ dig +short ip-10-10-x-y.eu-central-1.compute.internal
10.10.x.y
```

### How to solve this:

Either move your EMR clusters in the same region as your VPN is, or the other way around.

But the simplest solution might be to just use a Chrome plugin ([here's an example](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirector/ocgpenflpmgnfapjedencafcfakcekcd?hl=en)) that automatically redirects ip-x-y-z... URLS to x.y.z IPs.